# assigning ID's to body tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help on this guys,

I have here a script that adds an ID on body tag

this is the result I see

```
<body id="xxx-cat">
```

with the script I'm using below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// Edit xxx-cat to match desired category link id:
$('body').attr("id","xxx-cat");
if ($('body[id]')) {
var bid = $("body").attr("id");
// Keep the next command on one line
$('div.droplinebar li a[class='+bid+']').addClass('current');
}
})
</script>
```

How can I make the ID's (1,2,3,4), because I have 4 pages and want it like

```
<body id="1"> for the home page
<body id="2"> for the about
<body id="3"> for the clients
<body id="4"> for the contact
```

and by the way this is a tumblr custom page, can't use PHP here

Comment: Are these 4 body tags in same html?

Comment: there should be only one body in a page, why bother giving them different id's?

Comment: Note that HTML IDs must start with a letter (see [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)).

Comment: its because Im assigning different background to it

Comment: @Cymen That's not true according to the HTML5 spec and is not enforced by browsers even with HTML4

Comment: @Dennis Good point on HTML5 (couldn't find the correct page at w3.org with a quick search) but just because it's not enforced doesn't meant it isn't a good idea to follow the standard. If someone is asking a question like this, I'm going to assume they are using HTML4.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you can change the scripting, but not the page itself (because it is on Tumblr?)

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var bodyId = '1'; // Set to 1, 2, 3, 4 etc    
    $("body").attr('id', bodyId);
    $('div.droplinebar li a.'+bodyId).addClass('current');
});
```

However as mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't just use an number for your ID, consider revising this if possible.

Comment: can it be done like on
home = <body id="1">
about = <body id="2">
clients = <body id="3">
contact = <body id="4">

Comment: How are you able to tell what page you are on? Can you have different javascript per page, or can you change the markup etc?

Comment: how about assigning body ID's on a URL, can this be possible? 

http://mysite/
http://mysite/about
http://mysite/clients
http://mysite/contacts

sorry Im very new on this

Answer (score 1):

found an answer to My question

```
$(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var getLast = pathname.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1];
    var truePath = getLast.replace(".php","");
    if(truePath === '') {
        $('body').attr('id', 'home');
    }
    else {
        $('body').attr('id', truePath);
    }
});
```

results

```
home = <body id="home">
about = <body id="about">
clients = <body id="clients">
contacts = <body id="contacts">
```